# List item and statement html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code (a list item), and it works fine, when you click it, it drops down the list item, here is the code:

```
 <div class="list-item"> <strong class="table-cell">Choose:</strong> <span class="table-cell right">
          <!--     <input type="text" name="numberofchildren" id="numberofchildren" value="">                                       -->
          <select name="numberofchildren" id="numberofchildren" value="numberofchildren" >
            <option value="Blood Group" selected disabled>NO CHILDREN</option>
            <option value="No Children" >No Children</option>
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
            <option value="3" >3</option>
            <option value="4" >4</option>
            <option value="5" >5</option>
            <option value="6" >6</option>
            <option value="7" >7</option>
            <option value="8" >8</option>
            <option value="9" >9</option>
            <option value="10" >10</option>
          </select>
          </span> </div>
```

But my question is this, how can I add a javascript code, that when a user chooses, for example "1" ( if he chose == "1" {...}, how can I do that.

Hope that I was clear, thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: It was clear, yes; but you need to try to write this yourself and then, when - or *if* - that code doesn't work, come back to us and ask for help with that problematic code. Show us the ("[MCVE]") code, explain in what way it doesn't work, what you're expecting it to do, what it actually does, and any errors that might pop up in the console. But you first have to make an attempt; we're not a work-for-free service, we're here to *help*.

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas , thankyou for you response, you are so right, I would try it, i would try it with if statement, but I dont know how to make action when users chooses something from list menu, I searched on google but I couldn't find it, so how can I do something when user chooses one of these options. thank you again, and you are so right, hope that you don't misunderstand me.

Comment: @DavidThomas also I edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    function myfunction(select) {
        if (select.value == "1") {
          alert("You selected ONE");
        } else {
          alert("You selected: " + select.value);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <select name="numberofchildren" id="numberofchildren"
       value="numberofchildren" onchange="myfunction(this)">
      <option value="">Please select value...</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: hei @gavriel this is not working I added the function inside the <script></script> and onchange  outside, but it doesnt change something, can you be more clear, thank you very much.

Comment: I updated my answer with working code snippet, please try it, and you'll see it'll alert different text according to the value